# GDB - how can a breakpoint disable itself the best way?

Tags: gdb

If I have a breakpoint that has the number 8 for example. If I want this breakpoint to be disabled after it is hit, I write the following in `commands 8`:

```
disable 8
end
```

If I delete a breakpoint whose number is less than 8, then saved the breakpoints in a file before exiting gdb, the reopen gdb and restore the breakpoints file, the number of breakpoint 8 will change and its commands will disable the wrong breakpoint.

Is there a variable that I can use so that a breakpoint's command can disable itself? I mean some variable like `$bpnum`

Comment: Actually, there is a [`$bpnum` variable](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_6.html#SEC29), but it tells you the number of the most recently breakpoint.

Comment: If you can somehow get the number of the current line then you can use [`clear linenumber`](https://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/clear) to delete breakpoints in that line. The `frame` command can tell you that, but it does not return the line number so that you can use with the `clear` command. Maybe (probably?) you can do this using the python API.

Comment: I don't want to clear. I just want to disable. `$bpnum` tells the number of the last added breakpoint and not the last hit breakpoint, right?

Comment: @darcamo Thank you for referencing `clear` - the nice (and less known) thing about this is that you can also remove maintenance breakpoints this way (where `delete` says it won't remove negative number).

Answer (score 4):

If you're okay with the breakpoint being deleted, rather than disabled, you have [`tbreak`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html) (temporary break point), which erases the breakpoint as soon as it's hit. For catchpoints (`catch ...`), [`tcatch`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html) provides similar behavior.

If you want it to be disabled, you can use conditional breakpoints, with debugger convenience variables. Following on [gdb breakpoint conditions](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Conditions.html), you could do:

```
set $foo = 0
break 5
condition $foo++ < 1
```

Or alternatively, through commands:

```
break <line_num>
set $n $bpnum
commands
disable $n
end
```

Unfortunately, neither solution scales, unless you're willing to set breakpoints in a specific order. In that case, you could simply do:

```
break <line_num>
commands
disable 1
end
```

Where 1 is the first breakpoint, and it would be 2 for the second breakpoint, etc.